# Programmatically get pending payment orders and canceled orders?

Tags: orders, order-status

I can use this to get orders with status: `complete`, `processing`, `closed`.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter(
    array('status'), 
    array(
        array(
            array('eq' => 'complete'),
            array('eq' => 'processing'),
            array('eq' => 'pending_payment'),
            array('eq' => 'canceled'),
        ),
    )
);
```

However it doesn't return orders that are pending payment or canceled. How do I get the orders that are pending payment or canceled as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below code :

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('complete','processing','pending_payment','canceled')));
```